# Is there any way to get such type of line wrapping in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, formatting

Eclipse sure provides a lot of ways to customize code formatting, but I'm missing the one I'm used to. It is "when line exceeds maximum length, recursively wrap and indent each argument and put the closing parenthesis on a new line without additional indentation". Like this:

```
Horse samuel = new Horse(
    9.1051,
    Color.RED,
    new Music(1),
    new Music(
        "frying pan",
        Taste.SWEET,
        Russian.HELICOPTER
    ),
    State.ARIZONA
);
```

However it is not implemented in standard Eclipse formatting tools. Can I achieve this through some plugins? There is a 1.5 year old bug in Eclipse bug tracker, but it is unlikely to get any attention any time soon: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=370540

Comment: In the meantime, have you found a solution for this indentation scheme? It's exactly the style I'd like Eclipse to follow as well. While the bug has been fixed and "Line Wrapping -> Wrapping settings -> Function Calls -> Arguments -> Wrap all elements, every element on a new line" gets close, it doesn't wrap the parentheses as desired.

Comment: @ThomasW Nope, migrated to IDEA in 2015.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to have to create a custom profile formatter in eclipse to get it to do this. Window -> Prefrences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter

Under the Line Wrapping tab is the option for line width  = Maximum line width.  I think thats as good as it gets without that bug fix. 
Also, use the Line Wrapping policy  = Wrap all elements, every element on a new line. 
Thats as close as I could get it to do what you are asking.